# A font similar to Olay or Revlon?

Tags: font-recommendation

I am designing a logo for a skin care boutique. I want a font that is

- sleek
- elegant
- modern

I would like something similar to the Olay font, or the Rimmel font.

[image]

[image]

I'd prefer free, but I am not fussy.

Edit: I have searched buzzwords, but I am not finding anything. I know this is subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with buzzwords, did you look for "rimmel font" or for typographical terms.

If just the first and if you're new to typography, this style is called a **high contrast sans serif**. Contrast being thin strokes combined with thick strokes, and sans serif being the absence (sans) of curly endpoints (serif).

Looking through one of my favorite (free commercial) font sites, fontsquirrel, I sadly only found one such font, [COM4T Fine Regular](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/COM4t-Fine-Regular):
[image]

But there are plenty of fonts and sites with all sorts of prices. For example: [Grenoble (1 weight free, full pack $15)](http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/softmaker/grenoble-serial?font_sku=SSG1017016), [Darjeeling ($30 per weight)](http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/facetype/darjeeling?font_sku=FACE1010813), [Vanitas ($42 per weight)](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/reserves/vanitas/) or the classic [Bodoni Sans ($34 per weight)](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/greyscale-type/bodoni-sans/):
[image: Grenoble Serial]
[image: Darjeeling]
[image: Vanitas]
[image: Bodoni Sans]

Or you could look for a **didone** or **didot** font, which actually have serifs, but they are very thin (called hairline serifs), and get their high contrast through that as well.

Two examples from fontsquirrel are [Anglecia Pro Display](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/anglecia-pro-display) and [Theano Didot](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Theano-Didot):
[image: Anglecia Pro Display]
[image: Theano Didot]

Comment: Hi PixelSnader, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

I use [IdentiFont](http://www.identifont.com/) for this. It doesn't have every font in existence, but it can usually figure out what you're looking for from a few simple questions. I don't think either of these fonts are publicly available - the Olay font is a stylized version of some characters from Optima. [Euro Sans](http://www.identifont.com/show?271A) might fit the bill.